# Optimize query with AutoMapper on navigation property table

Tags: automapper

Use Automapper to expose OData with EF core, data model,

- Customer, one to many relation to Order
- Order

The Customer class has a ICollection of Order. Used Automapper queryable extension ProjectTo. All works fine.

However, looking at queries sent by EF to SQL, it always sending the queries to the Order even when there is no extend in the OData request. How to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the default behavior. You have to explicitly tell AM what you don't want it to fetch. See [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#explicit-expansion).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107973/explicitexpansion-on-navigation-property-cant-expand-now-automapper-with-ef-co#comment79179724_46107973